# Counting documents by field value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Could you please share the correct query to group by and count MongoDB documents by the field value of media type (e.g., foto, video, gif, etc.)?

This is an example of one of the documents:
[image: MongoDB Document]

This is the query that I'm currently using:

```
db.tweets.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$entities.media.type", count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

The current query is not returning the count of documents by media type:

[image: Current query]

Please find an example of one of the documents in JSON [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hGy4I69R6jrr3G59w1_kQyaMx1kkVF0Jb_8bXuE8ttA/edit?usp=sharing).

When I use the following query:

```
db.tweets.aggregate([ {"$group" : {_id:"$entities.media.type", count:{$sum:1}}} ]).forEach(function(doc){print(doc._id+", "+doc.count)})
```

I get:
[image: Modified query]

Thank you.

Comment: can you share the input document and output result in the JSON instead of the image? The aggregate function that you have used seems syntactically right. Also, does the field  'media type' present at the same hierarchy in all the records?

Comment: can you modify your query to this 
db.tweets.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$entities.media.type", count:{$sum:1}}}
]).forEach(function(doc){print(doc._id+", "+doc.count)})

wanted to see what you are getting under the attribute _id.

Comment: Please find the result of the query that you shared in the original question.

Comment: I shared a JSON document example in the question. And, yes, the field 'media type' present at the same hierarchy in all the records only when available. It is not available in many documents. Could you please help me get the query to count the documents by media type?

Comment: Did you get the required answer? In my opinion, your query and results are correct. You have a 'photo' appearing 809 times. The second item which has appeared photo, photo means in the type field you have an array of 2 elements which is why it is different than a single photo. And there are 20320 elements which do not have any value for the type field. 
Are you seeing any other value of type in the records?

Comment: Thank you Ajay. How do I unwind that array? I'm trying the following query and it's not working: db.tweets.aggregate([{$unwind : "$entities.media.type"}])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213046/discussion-between-eshra-and-ajay-kr-choudhary).